# The resultType of LinkedHashMap did retain column order of my sql

Tags: mybatis, linkedhashmap, mapper, columnsorting, resulttype

I have a free format sql which I passed into the myBatis mapper. I have set the resultType = "java.util.LinkedHashMap".  But the result returned did not retain the column order of my sql.  I have up to 65 columns in my sql select statement.  It is very important to keep the original order.  How can I make this work? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please add 1) the DB version and 2) the driver version.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.